# C# Form Application with database but without additional software

Tags: c#, .net, database, windows

I'm planning on creating a C# windows form application that will use a local database (for only one user).I dont know what software the client has installed on his computer but I want my application to work.It should have .NET installed ofc.
My question is , what kind of database can I implement (developing in Visual Studio 2012) that user , after starting my application, would be able to use without installing any additional software like servers.
I did have success with MS Access database but I heard here that this solution is depricated.

Comment: You're looking for an embedded database, of which there are many. Which one would be best for you depends on what you will be using it for, which you haven't told us. Also, product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: If you just have a few records, you could think about using an XML File. With LINQ to XML it's pretty easy to perform CRUD operations.

Comment: Well about usage, database will store information about wine cellar which does include minimum several tables and connections between them. Do you think that embedded databases could cover that? Maybe sql ce or sqllite would be ok? Thats some I heard about browsing the stack

Comment: If its not a significant amount of data or a busy database, I would go with SQLite. It really depends on your usage here, if you are planning on having the database being accessed from multiple clients, or hundreds of thousands of records with a high utilization, that changes things. We need to know more about what you are using the database for.

Comment: One client would use it and database will store information about N number of barrels which wont be greater then 50-60...so no large numbers of records and if its one client it shouldn't be "busy"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use single file/embedded databases like [Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html) or [SQL Server Compact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx)

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application) is an example on how to use Sqlite in .net application.